# How to alter the parameters in the core.services.yml file programatically?

Tags: 8, symfony-services

I need to modify the filter_protocols parameter inside the core.services.yml file programmatically to add a new protocol. I know how to alter a service but I don't find any information about how to alter a parameter.

```
parameters:
  session.storage.options:
    gc_probability: 1
    gc_divisor: 100
    gc_maxlifetime: 200000
    cookie_lifetime: 2000000
  twig.config:
    debug: false
    auto_reload: null
    cache: true
  renderer.config:
    required_cache_contexts: ['languages:language_interface', 'theme', 'user.permissions']
    auto_placeholder_conditions:
      max-age: 0
      contexts: ['session', 'user']
      tags: []
  factory.keyvalue:
    default: keyvalue.database
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: false
  factory.keyvalue.expirable:
    default: keyvalue.expirable.database
  filter_protocols:
    - http
    - https
    - ftp
    - news
    - nntp
    - tel
    - telnet
    - mailto
    - irc
    - ssh
    - sftp
    - webcal
    - rtsp
```

I know how to do this by copying the services.yml file inside the sites/default folder but at this time I need to do this programmatically.

Any idea about how to do it?

Comment: You need to add a compiler pass. See for example how the serializer formats are collected in RegisterSerializationClassesCompilerPass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [compiler pass](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html):

> Compiler passes give you an opportunity to manipulate other service
> definitions that have been registered with the service container.

There are some Drupal specifics. An example which calculates a container parameter depending on tagged services is [RegisterSerializationClassesCompilerPass](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21serialization%21src%21RegisterSerializationClassesCompilerPass.php/function/RegisterSerializationClassesCompilerPass%3A%3Aprocess/9.1.x). This class is registered in [SerializationServiceProvider](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21serialization%21src%21SerializationServiceProvider.php/function/SerializationServiceProvider%3A%3Aregister/9.1.x).

For simple use cases, where you don't need control over compiler pass priorities, you can use the `alter()` method of ServiceModifierInterface. This will then be executed in a shared core compiler pass [ModifyServiceDefinitionsPass](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DependencyInjection%21Compiler%21ModifyServiceDefinitionsPass.php/function/ModifyServiceDefinitionsPass%3A%3Aprocess/9.1.x).

Example for adding `foo` to the filter protocols:

*src/MymoduleServiceProvider.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule;

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderBase;

/**
 * Defines a service provider for the Mymodule module.
 */
class MymoduleServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $filter_protocols = $container->getParameter('filter_protocols');
    $filter_protocols[] = 'foo';
    $container->setParameter('filter_protocols', $filter_protocols);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @4k4 great answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you run script from Drupal root folder:

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

$root = __DIR__; 

$config = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($root . '/core/config/install/core.extension.yml'));

$config['parameters']['filter_protocols'][] = 'NEW_PROTOCOL'; // Your protocol

$yaml = Yaml::dump($config);
file_put_contents($root . '/core/config/install/core.extension.yml', $yaml);
```

Comment: I think is not a god idea to modify core files

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I directly answer for your question. Question: what core.extension.yml do you want modify? 
In sync folder? 
On what event (manually, config export, ...)?

Comment: Sorry, I just see I wrote the wrong file name, is core.services.yml